# Save and open pdf (Javascript-Cordova-Android)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I´m trying to save a pdf (generated with jspdf) and then open, just 2 buttons, but nothing happens on device and on console no error is shown.

This is the code to save:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {
      dir.getFile("cotizacion.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                   writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                          console.log("Escritura exitosa");
                   };
                   console.log("Escribiendo...");
                   writer.write(window.cotizacion);
            })
            },function () {
               console.log("Error al guardar");
            });
});
```

And this is to open:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {
      dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) { //EXISTS
            var url = "file:/" + cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "/cotizacion.pdf";
                window.open(url, '_system');
                    }, function() { 
                        //NOT EXISTS
                        alert('Hubo un problema al recuperar la cotización');
                    });
});
```

What can I do to make it work?

Thank you all.

PS: I have all the plugins File, FileTransfer, InAppBrowser

Comment: Try to open the downloaded file with this plugin :


  [1]: https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing happens on device and in Intel XDK opens a new empty window

Comment: Have you check that if the file be downloaded correctly on device?

Comment: You´re right they not appear, but with other methods they appear but with other (base64?), with extension bin and size 0. I saw other posts and this trivial thng seems to be almost imposible with cordova

Comment: No it is possible I've done it two years ago.try to download the file using this tut:https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/01/Cordova-Sample-Check-for-a-file-and-download-if-it-isnt-there/

Comment: Finally I can do it splitting the problem to: *One button to create the document *One button to create the pdf content *One button to write the pdf content into the created document *One button to open the file *Only Cordova File plugin And following and adapting the solution in this post:
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/60 Later I´ll do a video tutorial because this issue seems to be common and hard to solve.